# How do I resolve SSRS Chart Axis issue

Tags: reporting-services, charts, report

Wondering if I could get help.

I need to be able to view my report within 0-100%, but the chart is showing from 2000 to 12000 on my Y axis

[image]

Comment: right-click the Y axis and choose properties. You can fix the Y axis min and max values from there . However the axis will normally be based on the values provided so you would need to show the results of your dataset query if you are still struggling

Comment: Thanks Alan, really helpful